# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined (reportschannel.send) discord.js

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I'm making a report command and got this erorr

```
reportsChannel.send(`**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for 
                ^
**${reason}**.`);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

This error only happens when I'm in a different server than the channel where all reports are stored

here is my code:

```
 switch(args[0]){
        case 'report':
            let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if(!target) return message.channel.send('Please provide a user that you wish to report').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}));

            var reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
            if(!reason) return message.channel.send(`Please provide a reason for reporting **${target.user.username}**`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}));
   
            let reportsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === "747697771594645566")
   
            if(args[1] === target, args[2] === reason){
                message.channel.send('Your report has been filled to the staff team. Thank you for reporting!')
                reportsChannel.send(`**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for **${reason}**.`);
            }
        break;
      };
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me make a clarification, in a different server you cannot get it's guild through `message.guild` it will return on the server where it's on...
So, change this:

```
let reportsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === "747697771594645566")
```

to this:

```
let reportsChannel = client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === "747697771594645566")
```

Comment: You could also skip the `guild` part and just do `message.client.channels.cache.get()`

Comment: That's great, I wasn't checking on that, tend to do stuff the hard way xd.